Spring Reactive - Redis Health Check Failing
I have enabled my application to use the actuator/health endpoint and kept getting the status as 'DOWN'. After checking the full health endpoint details, I can see that I am getting two reponses for the redis health check, one for the reactive redis connection and one for the non-reactive redis connection. In our configuration class, we are only uisng the ReactiveRedisConnectionFactory class, so I wanted to try and see if there is a way to disable the non-reactive one / what others have done to get around this issue.
I did see the below thread, but it seemed more of a workaround, rather than actually looking into why there are two connections. - Spring Boot Reactive Redis 2 connection factories causing health check fail
    @SneakyThrows
    @Bean
    public TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory() {

        KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        trustStore.load(null, null);

        InputStream certIS = new ByteArrayInputStream(serverCA.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        trustStore.setCertificateEntry("serverCA", CertificateFactory.getInstance("X509").generateCertificate(certIS));

        TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        trustManagerFactory.init(trustStore);
        return trustManagerFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public RedisStandaloneConfiguration redisStandaloneConfiguration() {
        RedisStandaloneConfiguration redisStandaloneConfiguration = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration(redisHost, redisPort);
        redisStandaloneConfiguration.setPassword(redisPassword);
        return redisStandaloneConfiguration;
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public ReactiveRedisConnectionFactory reactiveRedisConnectionFactory() {

        SslOptions sslOptions = SslOptions.builder().trustManager(trustManagerFactory())
                .jdkSslProvider()
                .build();

        ClientOptions clientOptions = ClientOptions.builder().sslOptions(sslOptions).build();

        LettuceClientConfiguration.LettuceClientConfigurationBuilder clientConfigurationBuilder = LettuceClientConfiguration.builder();

        LettuceClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = clientConfigurationBuilder
            .clientOptions(clientOptions)
            .useSsl()
            .build();

        return new LettuceConnectionFactory(redisStandaloneConfiguration(), clientConfiguration);
    }

Health check results:
{
  "status": "DOWN",
  "components": {
    "redis": {
      "status": "DOWN",
      "components": {
        "reactiveRedisConnectionFactory": {
          "status": "UP",
          "details": {
            "version": "7.0.14"
          }
        },
        "redisConnectionFactory": {
          "status": "DOWN",
          "details": {
            "error": "org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException: Unable to connect to Redis"
          }
        }
      }
    },
  }
}

